# Prevent text from wrapping in an absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to create a suggestbox but the items in my "dropdown" wrap. I would like them to take as much space horizontally as they need.

How can I tell the menu to take as much space as its children need horizontally?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.container > input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="menu">
    <span class="item">a very very very very long item</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89d2z95t/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An absolutely positioned element has a bounding box which is set by the nearest positioned ancestor ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)). This out-of-flow element is confined by those boundaries.

In your code, since the nearest positioned ancestor (`.container`) has a fixed width of 200px, the absolutely-positioned descendant (`.menu`) cannot exceed that limit. Therefore, the text wraps.

You can force the element to overflow the bounding box with [**`white-space: nowrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.container>input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap; /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="menu">
    <span class="item">a very very very very long item</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `.container` you could specify `min-width: 200px;` instead of an absolute width, which will allow it to stretch horizontally with its children.

Then also to prevent even larger spans you could enforce it to never wrap:

```
.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update to your jsfiddle, set your input's `width:200px`

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container > input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:200px;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="menu">
    <span class="item">a very very very very long item</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that but I don't want to change the container's width because I place a caret on the right side of the input (<input ...><span class="caret" style="position:absolute;right:.5em;"></span>), so I need the container to be the same width as the input.